# Kotlin array In array?

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I want to make a array in array and get one by index form in Kotlin.

for example, I make a this array [ (1, 12(real data is Bitmap)) , (2, 24(same)), (3, 36) ]

so I can get `array(index) = 12`

how can I make this form of array and get data by index like above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [`Map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/) is what you need:

```
val map = mapOf(1 to 12, 2 to 24, 3 to 36)
val twelve = map[1]
```

It is a collection that holds pairs of objects (keys and values) and supports efficiently retrieving the value corresponding to each key.

To add data to a map we can use `mutableMapOf` function:

```
val map = mutableMapOf<Int, Bitmap>()
val bitmap: Bitmap = ...
map[4] = bitmap
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, can i add bitmap data to mapOf array dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an array of bytes, use [`byteArrayOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/byte-array-of.html):

```
val array = byteArrayOf(12, 24, 36)
println(array[0]) // 12
```

`ByteArray` is the equivalent of Java's `byte[]`.

Note: There is also `intArrayOf`, `floatArrayOf`, `doubleArrayOf` etc.

---

Since you asked for an array in an array as well:

```
val arrayOfArrays = arrayOf(byteArrayOf(1, 2, 3), byteArrayOf(24), byteArrayOf(36))
println(arrayOfArrays[0][1]) // 2
```

In this case the type of `arrayOfArrays` will be `Array<ByteArray>` and you need `arrayOf` to construct that.